# Cannot find how to disable a screensaver

Tags: kubuntu, screensaver

Sorry for a 2nd stupid question in a row.
Can you please tell me how to disable screensavers in Kubuntu? I cannot even watch a movie without it popping up every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

- Go to Settings > System Settings > Desktop > Screensaver to turn off the screensaver.